# GNUS - mark all articles in the thread as Unread

Tags: gnus, email, imap

I was searching through docs at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/ but could not find the proper key sequence for this. What is the key sequence for this?

Comment: Have you tried running the command that marks an article as read on a region? If it works on the region, prefixing it with C-x h should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
3.9.2 Thread Commands
---------------------
‘T k’
‘C-M-k’
     Mark all articles in the current (sub-)thread as read
     (‘gnus-summary-kill-thread’).  If the prefix argument is positive,
     remove all marks instead.  If the prefix argument is negative, tick
     articles instead.
```

— `(info "(gnus) Thread Commands")`

And please do not ask me, how should you guess this without readind the manual, or why `M-u` does not work on ‘process marked’ articles.